# Javascript - building a list of all LI with a given ID and click every one

Tags: javascript

I have a list that is built like this:

```
<ul id="ajaxList" class="ajaxListUL">
```

and then, every element of the list is like this

```
<li class="ajaxListLI" id="ajaxListRow_32412312">
```

this number 32412312 is random. Every element of the list has one 
number there, like

```
<li class="ajaxListLI" id="ajaxListRow_32443232"> ...
<li class="ajaxListLI" id="ajaxListRow_86752312"> ...
<li class="ajaxListLI" id="ajaxListRow_35644312"> ...
```

etc.

every LI is clickable, and I need to make a loop to click every one.

but the list has also elements like this

```
<li class="ajaxListXT"> ...
```

that are not clickable.

What I need to do is to build an array of all LI elements on the page that IDs start by "ajaxListRow_" and click them.

I did this so far:

```
var children = document.getElementById('ajaxList').childNodes;
var length = children.length;
  var elements = [];
  var child;
  for (i = 0;  i < length; i++) {
    child = children[i];
    if (child.id.substring(0, 12) == "ajaxListRow_")
      elements.push(child);
      document.child.click();
  }
```

it stops on the IF line, complaining about the id stuff.
I have tried to remove the id, without success.

At this point I don't even know if these lines are correct:

```
 elements.push(child);
  document.child.click();
```

for adding a LI to the array and to click that li.

How do I do that? 
thanks.

Comment: Use jQuery and make a `$.each` loop where it loops over every li with the `id` attribute

Comment: can you elaborate and make it an answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function getElementsByClassName(classname, node)  {
    if(!node) node = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    var a = [];
    var re = new RegExp('\\b' + classname + '\\b');
    var els = node.getElementsByTagName("*");
    for(var i=0,j=els.length; i<j; i++)
        if(re.test(els[i].className))
           a.push(els[i]);
    return a;
}

var childs = getElementsByClassName("ajaxListLI",document.getElementById('ajaxList'));
for(var i = 0; i<childs.length; i++){
   childs[i].click();
}
```

Comment: inside the function you have classname and className... is this correct?

Comment: yes one of them for filter, i mean for example "ajaxListLI". the other one is fpr getting elements className. so it is correct. i tried it on IE and it is working.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.children` instead of `.childNodes`, otherwise you'll get the empty text nodes that separate the `<li>` elements.

```
var children = document.getElementById('ajaxList').children; // .children
var length = children.length;
var elements = [];
var child;
for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    child = children[i];
    if (child.id.substring(0, 12) == "ajaxListRow_") elements.push(child);
    document.child.click();
}
```

Also `document.child.click();` doesn't seem right. You may mean `child.click();`, though I'm not sure it will actually trigger the handler.

And I may be inclined to replace:

```
if(child.id.substring(0, 12) == "ajaxListRow_")
```

with this instead:

```
if(child.id.indexOf("ajaxListRow_") === 0)
```

but that's just a preference.

Comment: thanks. the code seems to be right, but it is not clicking anything, unfortunately.